# When getting the cross product of two vectors, is the i value initially positive or negative? [ERROR ON MY END]

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, vectors, 3d

[upon further discussion it appears this was just a sign error when performing operations with the matrix (comments in first answer)]

given
$$
\vec{u} = \frac{1}{2}   i  -1j+\frac{2} {3}   k  ,\  
\vec{v} = 6 i  -12 j  -6 k  ,
$$

We can cross multiply these vectors to find a vector that is perpendicular or orthogonal to both of them. Two of these vectors exist and you can get them both by swapping the order you multiply them in. ($u\times v$ and $v\times u$)
Apparently when we cross multiply these vectors we get $-2 i   -1 j   +0 k  $ or $14 i  +7 i  +0 k  $ depending on which order you multiply them.

I understand $-2 i   -1 j   +0 k  $ but why is it we get $14 i  +7 i  +0 k  $ instead of $-14 i  +7 i  +0 k  $ if the determinant of the i matrix when we cross multiply is $-14$ not $+14$. Is the value of i being switched here?

There is also the possibility that $14 i  +7 i  +0 k  $ is incorrect. Do let me know if that's the case.

Comment: Well, $u\times v = -v\times u$.

Comment: Hint: To cross two vectors, convert the left operant and the cross product into matrix

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y\\z} \times \pmatrix{a \\ b\\ c} = \left| \matrix{0&-z&y \\ z & 0 & -x\\-y & x & 0} \right| \pmatrix{a \\ b\\ c} = \pmatrix{y\, c-z b \\ z\, a - x\, c \\ x\, b - y\, a }$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a determinant to find the cross product use the following pattern $$\begin {bmatrix} +&-&+\\-&+&-\\+&-&+\end{bmatrix}$$

For example (3i+2j-3k)\time (2i+5j+k) = det $$\begin {bmatrix} i&j&k\\3&2&-3\\2&5&1\end{bmatrix} =$$

$$i(17)-j(9)+k(11)=17i-9j+11k$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec{u} \times \vec{v} = \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ \frac12 & -1 & \frac23 \\ 6 & -12 & -6\end{vmatrix}= 14i + 7j$$

Recall that when we switch rows, the determinant gets multiplied by $-1$,
$$\vec{v} \times \vec{u} =  -(14i + 7j)$$

$-2i-j$ is not the right answer.

Edit:

notice that $$\begin{vmatrix} -12 & -6 \\-1 & \frac23\end{vmatrix}=-8-(-1)(-6)=-14$$

Comment: So you're saying that if we swap rows we don't find the matrix determinant as we would normally? If we just swapped the row we would end up doing $(6-8)i- ((-3)+4)j+ ((-6)+6)k$. Why is this not the correct answer?

Comment: I suspect you made a sign error somwhere, i have edited my answer to compute the $i$ component. try to see if you can spot the mistake.

Comment: Wow you're right it was a sign error. Sorry. Though I am intrigued by the fact that it was still counted right on my assignment. It seems that -2i-j is still perpendicular to the vectors but it's just not what you get when you perform the matrix operations correctly.

Comment: @RustyRaptor: Of course: $-7 (-2i - j) = 14i + 7j$.

Comment: I wonder. Is it just a coincidence that you get the answer when making a sign error or is there some sort of property that makes that happen?

Comment: hmmm... I still do not know your mistake exactly... I just know it is some sort of sign mistake. Is your mistake doing $ad+bc$ when computing determinant?